# System locks up randomly playing video - Nvidia-375

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, video

Tested on Ubuntu 16.10, 17.04, and Linux Mint using the nvidia-375 proprietary drivers.
When playing video, The system will randomly freeze up completely and stop responding until reboot (you can hear the speakers make a ksssst noise). Accelerated video games have no problems.
Issue occurs when playing video locally or watching videos in a browser.
Video card is ZOTAC GeForce GTX 1060 Mini, ZT-P10600A-10L, 6GB GDDR5 Super Compact.